# Render two volumes simultaneously by blending them using image plane widget

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I am trying to visualize some 3D scalar data in mayavi. I am able to visualize the data individually by using the image plane widget. My goal is to blend two different scalar volumes of same size and spacing and display them using image plane widget.

I have already tried using image plane widget. Changing the opacity of the ipw but to no avail , mayavi instead of blending two cubes treats them separately .

```
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np
import util 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
from mayavi import mlab

in_path = '/home/user/Desktop/Attribute_Extract_v_0.1/small_vol.hdf5'
in_path_2 = '/home/user/Desktop/Attribute_Extract_v_0.1/anu_malik.hdf5'

data = util.read(in_path)
data_2 = util.read(in_path_2)

shaped_data_2 = np.array(data_2)
shaped_data = np.array(data)
print(shaped_data.shape)


vm = np.percentile(shaped_data,99)
vm2 = np.percentile(shaped_data_2,99)

vm_3 = np.percentile(shaped_data_2,20)
vm_4 = np.percentile(shaped_data_2,80)

#Use mayavi to plot the 3D seismic cube with xline , inline and , Timeslice 

source = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(shaped_data)
source_2 = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(shaped_data_2)
source.spacing = [1, 1, -1]
source_2.spacing = [1, 1, -1]

vol = mlab.pipeline.volume(source_2, vmin=vm_3, vmax=vm_4)

for axis in ['x', 'y',  'z']:


    plane = mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget(source_2, 
                                    plane_orientation='{}_axes'.format(axis),
                                    slice_index=100, colormap='Spectral',opacity=0.2,  vmin=-vm2, vmax=vm2 )

    plane_2 = mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget(source, 
                                    plane_orientation='{}_axes'.format(axis),
                                    slice_index=100, colormap='seismic',opacity=0.5,  vmin=-vm, vmax=vm )
    # Flip colormap. you can choose to ignore
    plane.module_manager.scalar_lut_manager.reverse_lut = True




mlab.outline()
mlab.show()
```

results : [image: results two different volumes not blended]

I want the two volumes to be blended and only one ipw visible , is there any way to achieve it.

same slice_index : 
[image]

Comment: @joe kington , can you please give some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to update the slice_index for each dataset and each axis. Looking at your figure, both XY planes are plotted at the same location, but it is not the case for XZ and YZ. This likely means that, given a plane orientation, the slice_index does not represent the same spatial_location for both datasets.

Now, assuming you fix this and both sets of image_plane_widget perfectly overlap, how do you actually want to blend them and be able to distinguish them at the same time? Opacity might be the only choice here, and you may want to use [plane_opacity](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_pipeline_other_functions.html?highlight=image_plane#mayavi.tools.pipeline.image_plane_widget). Another option would be to plot one dataset as it is now, and then to plot meaningful [contours](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html?highlight=contour_surf#mayavi.mlab.contour_surf) of the second dataset on top of it.

EDIT: I could not manage to apply any opacity to either a volume_slice or an image_plane_widget. However, it seems to work with scalar_cut_plane. The way the location of the plane is set is unfortunately different.

```
scp = mlab.pipeline.scalar_cut_plane(
    mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(data), plane_orientation='y_axes', opacity=0.5)
scp.implicit_plane.widget.origin = np.array([X, Y , Z])
scp.implicit_plane.widget.enabled = False
```

Comment: @Patrol75 thanks for the answer, I am adjusting the opacity to different levels like 0.5 and 0.7 for two different volumes , but still one of them appears to be perfectly opaque

Comment: I have made the slice index same now aw well , question edited

Comment: Did you try plane_opacity instead of opacity?

Comment: plane = mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget(source_2, 
                                    plane_orientation='{}_axes'.format(axis),
                                    slice_index=100, colormap='seismic',plane_opacity=0.7 )

    plane_2 = mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget(source, 
                                    plane_orientation='{}_axes'.format(axis),
                                    slice_index=100, colormap='PuBu',plane_opacity=0.5 )

Comment: I will try making a reproducible example with user defined data set

Comment: What if you set both opacity and plane_opacity to 0 for the first source and to 1 for the second one? What if you do the opposite? Is it still the same plane that is visible?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you should be able to make it work now. I have no idea why the keywords do not work with image_plane_widget...